# Custom mobile navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im trying to write my own simple, animating mobile navigation...

I have a basic working version of it but I cant quite get it to go back correctly...

If you click 'products' the sub menu appears, at the top of the submenu it says '< products', once clicked that menu should then slide back out, only it does nothing...

Im not sure if my top function is running everytime you click any of the links? hopefully the jsfiddle makes more sense...

http://jsfiddle.net/0o5jppts/

```
$('.mobile-nav ul.parent-level li').on('click', function (e) {
   $('ul.level-one').css('left', 0);
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log('clicked;');
});
 $('.mobile-nav ul.level-one li').on('click', function (e) {
   if (!$(this).hasClass('back-title')) {
       $('ul.level-two').css('left', 0);
   }
   e.preventDefault();
});
    //alert('go back');
   $(this).parent().css('left', '120px');
});
```

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't really make any more sense. If you can't clearly state the problem, we can't help you! What is happening that's wrong, and what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Updated my question sorry @nkorth

Comment: By the way, the second level of navigation isn't going to work as you expect because your selectors are too broad. For example, the first click handler should probably be on `.mobile-nav ul.parent-level > li`. See [CSS Child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem! When `li.back-title` is clicked, the third click handler is called, setting the `left` of `ul.level-one` to `100px`, and then the first click handler is called, setting it back to `0` as if nothing happened. The fix is to call [`e.stopPropagation();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) at the end of the third click handler.